# iOS - allow user to add Calendar Event with some fields filled in

Tags: ios, calendar

Is it possible in Objective-C in xCode to open up the native iPhone "Add Event" calendar prompt with a couple of fields already filled in? For instance name, address and start/end date? If so, how?
This would allow the user to still change a couple of parameters: when does he want to be alerted, etc.

I have looked around but all I have found are methods to automatically add the event without the confirmation of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I handled it...with EKEventEditViewController!

First:

```
@import EventKitUI;
```

At the very top of your .m file.
Then set the `EKEventEditViewDelegate`

Then, when you want to add the event, use the following method:

```
- (IBAction)addToCalendar:(id)sender {
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        // the selector is available, so we must be on iOS 6 or newer
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    // display error message here
                }
                else if (!granted)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@ acce sdenied", error);
                    // display access denied error message here
                }
                else
                {
                    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: eventStore];
                    event.title = nom;
                    event.location = adresse;

                    // Set the start and end dates to the event.
                    event.startDate = startDate;
                    event.endDate = endDate; //
                    EKEventEditViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
                    eventViewController.event = event;
                    eventViewController.eventStore=eventStore;
                    eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
                    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                    [eventViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
                    [self presentViewController:eventViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
                }
            });
        }];
    }
}
```

Finally, add this delegate method to handle the completion action:

```
-(void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
         didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {
    NSError *error;
    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCancelled:
            // User tapped "cancel"
            NSLog(@"Canceled");
            break;
        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            NSLog(@"Saved");
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span: EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
            [calendarBouton setTitle:@"Ajouté!" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
            calendarBouton.enabled = NO;
            break;
        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            // User tapped "delete"
            NSLog(@"Deleted");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**
 First take Calendar Permission

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    [self.eventManager.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {



        if(granted==NO)
        {

            BOOL permission=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CalendarPermissionAlert"];

            if(permission==NO) {

                kAppDelegateObject.eventManager.eventsAccessGranted=NO;

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"CalendarPermissionAlert"];

                UIAlertView   * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Calendar Access is OFF"
                                                                   message:kCalenderResetMessage
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:@"SETTING",nil];
                [alert show];
                alert.tag=101;

                return ;
            }


        }
```

**Step 2**

//Add Event

```
-(void)addEventWithMessage:(NSString*)eventMessage withEventDate:(NSDate *)eventDate
 EKEventStore *eventStore;
 eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

// Create a new event object.
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: eventStore];

```
// Set the event title.
event.title = eventMessage;

// Set its calendar.


NSString *identifier=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"calenderId"]; //your application id 
 // NSLog(@"cal identifier: %@",identifier);
event.calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:identifier];

//set Alarm
NSTimeInterval secondsInOneHours = 1 * 60 * 60;

NSDate *dateOneHoursAhead = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInOneHours];

// Set the start and end dates to the event.
event.startDate = eventDate;
event.endDate = dateOneHoursAhead; //

NSError *error;
    if ([eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&error]) {

  //  NSLog(@"Event Added");
}
else{
    // An error occurred, so log the error description.
  //  NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please reindent your code correctly? It's tough to see what is actually in the code or isn't! Thanks alot

Comment: Where does EventManager come from?

Comment: EventManager is NSObject class here i have declare  EKEventStore object.

EventManager.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) EKEventStore *eventStore;


EventManager.m

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        
       eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

}
return self;
}